# What happened to the flags on superuser?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Used to be that "not a real question" was one.  Now, it says something silly like "Unclear what is being asked", to which I immediately thought, "Oh, it's clear what they want.  But it both isn't a question, and will never see an answer because the way they declared what they want, and the final result will never see the light of day.

https://superuser.com/questions/612243/how-to-create-our-own-codec-for-a-media-player

Should I maybe have tagged it as low quality?  Or just downvoted it instead of flagging it as "Unclear what is being asked" (which used to be "not a question")

Comment: Full description of changes: [Closing changes: \[on hold\], unclear, too broad, opinion-based, off-topic reasons, bye-bye to Too Localized](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/184154)

Comment: @Sathya I don't think markdown likes [] within []

Comment: @tombull89 yep, corrected

Answer (score 6):

There are various reasons why this question would be off topic.

- It's about software (codec) development.
- And even if it *were* on topic: It's unclear what's being asked. It might be clear what they want—like asking "How do I drive a car?". You should interpret this option as "this question is too vague and unspecific". It wouldn't be possible to give a reasonably scoped answer without much guesswork.
- It's too broad, as entire books could be written on codec design.

By the way, the old option read "not a *real* question". So while in fact there could have been a question, it should be phrased in such a way that it is useful for Stack Exchange sites.

You should not flag anything as *very low quality* unless the post cannot be salvaged through editing and needs to be deleted right away. In almost any case, it's preferred to flag the question using a close option if it applies, or to fix it otherwise. If it can't be closed but can also not be edited into better shape, then flag as *very low quality*, but use this flag sparingly please.